# Receiving a swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional Error when Moving to a New Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, dynamic-cast

I am creating a SpriteKit game and received this error when trying to move to a new scene from my main view controller after the play button is pressed:

> swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional

Below is my code for my MenuViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as PlayScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    //Variables and Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func PlayButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
if let scene = PlayScene.unarchiveFromFile("PlayScene") as? PlayScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Here is my PlayScene (the scene I am trying to move to) code:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class PlayScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 190/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

I do not have much code in either of these files, since I just started, but I am already getting this error!  I have done this many times before, but I never got this error until now.  Here is what the debugger says:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x10d080620:  pushq  %rbp
0x10d080621:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10d080624:  pushq  %rbx
0x10d080625:  pushq  %rax
0x10d080626:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x10d080629:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x10d08062c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x10d08062e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x10d080631:  je     0x10d08064c               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x10d080633:  movq   0x82756(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x10d08063a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x10d08063d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x10d080640:  callq  0x10d0831ca               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10d080645:  testb  %al, %al
0x10d080647:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x10d08064a:  je     0x10d080653               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x10d08064c:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x10d080650:  popq   %rbx
0x10d080651:  popq   %rbp
0x10d080652:  retq   
0x10d080653:  leaq   0xcdc8(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10d08065a:  movq   %rax, 0x8ae57(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10d080661:  int3   
0x10d080662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I am using the new SpriteKit editor, and that is why I need to use the unarchiveFromFile method.  As I mentioned in one of my comments below, I figured out what code works.  However, I do not understand how the optional could affect the code and trigger it to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: is the PlayScene.sks set to return an instance of the PlayScene class or does it just return a SKScene?

Comment: Is the viewController's view actually an SKView? - if not, casting it to one will cause this error

Comment: The ViewController's view is just a regular UIView, but you try to cast it as a  SKView to an SKView; is this a problem?  If so, can you suggest some code?

Comment: I found if the code looks like the one in this link ([code](http://thewonderfulimagination.weebly.com/used-with-this-code-it-actually-works.html)), it works, but if it does not have the "as?" optional, it will not work.  It would be really helpful if someone could explain why.  Thanks for being so patient with me!